# "textAllCaps=false" does not work for textview?

Tags: android, xml, textview

I am using custom list view with sections. I am using below xml for the section layout

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:text="Large Text"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:background="#c3c3e5"
android:id="@+id/tv_li_section"
android:padding="8dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

Here textAllCaps= false is not working for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you want to show all text in lower case?

Comment: `android:textAllCaps="false" ` will not work if your original string is in uppercase:  `android:text="LARGE TEXT"`

Comment: which Android Support Library you are using??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the actual data coming from the listview is in Capitals, that is why this property was not working and items were showing as it is.

Answer (score 2):

By default `textAllCaps` is `false` for `TextView` there are chances that the data your are filling to `List` is having capital text in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AppCompat 23.2.0 android support library then Update for design library 23.2.0+

and You can use this style and define this in xml

```
<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
      <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
      <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

For reference you can see this `https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202117`